# using ngram in python

Tags: python

i'm trying to run the following code

```
       from ngram import NGram
       NGram.compare('foo', 'foobar')
```

But i'm getting the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "E:/pt/tandra", line 1, in <module>
    from ngram import Ngram
    ImportError: No module named ngram
```

what could be the possible reason. The ngram folder is in the same directory as the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have module called ngram. You need to install it.
Just use

```
easy_install ngram
```

or

```
pip install ngram
```

in terminal (for Linux, Mac OS, Cygwin in Windows) if you have python setuptools.