# error while importing ngram in python

Tags: python

I have installed ngram using pip install ngram. While I am running the following code

```
from ngram import NGram
c=NGram.compare('cereal_crop','cereals')
print c
```

I get the error `ImportError: cannot import name NGram`

Screenshot for it: [image: screenshot of console window]

P.S. A similar question has been asked previously [using ngram in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390585/using-ngram-in-python/43818866?noredirect=1#comment74676421_43818866), but that time the person who was getting error did not install ngram, so installing ngram worked. In my case I am getting the error in spite of ngram being installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python script is named `ngram.py`, so it defines a module named `ngram`.  When Python runs `from ngram import NGram`, Python ends up looking in your script for something named `NGram`, not in the `ngram` module you have installed.

Try changing the name of your script to something else, for example `ngram_test.py`.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
import ngram
c = ngram.NGram.compare('cereal_crop','cereals')
print c
```